# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ‘['

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on a problem:

> Let’s say I give you a list saved in a variable: a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]. Write one line of Python that takes this list a and makes a new list that has only the even elements of this list in it.

The code that I wrote is:

```
listtt=[]

listt=input(‘Please type in the list:')

for i in range(int(len(listt))):
    if (int(listt[i])%2)==0:
        listtt.append(listt[i]) # This will add the number in the given list to the empty list ‘listtt'
    else:
        pass

print(listtt)
```

Python displays an error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ‘[‘`

I read somewhere on StackOverflow that this means that Python thinks that I am trying to convert `’[‘` to an integer.

How am I trying to cover it to an integer? And how do I get rid of this error?

Comment: The syntax highlight should be a clue.... You are using an incorrect accent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to filter even numbers, try `[x for x in old_list if x%2==0]` as following codes.

```
In [39]: old_list = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

In [40]: new_list = [x for x in old_list if x%2==0]

In [41]: new_list
Out[41]: [4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

For your code:

```
listt=input('Please type in the list:')
# input should be separated with comma ',', without '[' and ']'
listt = listt.split(',')

new_list = [int(x) for x in listt if int(x)%2==0]

print(new_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you please tell me what mistake did I make and how to correct it rather than just telling me how to correct it!?

Comment: `input()` returns strings, so `listt` is a string.  It looks like you typed `[1, 4, 9, 16 ...]` as input to your program, so on the first time through your loop, `listt[i]` will be the first character, a left square bracket.

Comment: @AaryanDewan Problem at `listt=input('Please type in the list:')`. This would not get what you want, it just gives you a string `[1,2,3]`.

Comment: @JohnGordon , It doesn’t work even when I write `listt=list(input(‘Please type in the list:’))`

Comment: @AaryanDewan calling `list(input(...))` just gives you the individual characters of the typed input, arranged as a list instead of one large string.  They're never converted to integers.

Comment: @JohnGordon , I made a change to my code. I introduced `Jim` as `Jim=print(listt)` . Now `Jim` is a list. Then I replaced all the `listt` by `Jim` and I got an error : `TypeError: object of type ‘NoneType’ has no len()`! Where am I wrong?

Comment: _Now `Jim` is a list_ No it is not.  print() returns nothing. Jim is `None`, as the error message says.

Comment: @JohnGordon . You see, input () will return a string like, say `’[1,2,3,4,5,6]’`. Now doesn’t `print(‘[1,2,3,4,5,6]’)` return a list?

Comment: @AaryanDewan No.  As I already said, the return value of `print()` is `None`.  It _displays_ stuff on the screen, but that's not the same as _returning_ it.

Comment: @JohnGordon, how do I do it then? Do I have to define a function to use `return`? Or is there some other way to do it?

Comment: @AaryanDewan Honestly, I don't know exactly _what_ you are trying to do here.  The problem description you included in your question did not say anything about the user _typing in_ the list of numbers, so why are you trying to do that?  It seems like you have requirements you haven't told us.

Comment: @JohnGordon , what I am trying to do is to make a program that would run in the IDE which would ask the user to enter a list ( containing only numbers ) and then make another list which contains only even numbers from that list.

Comment: @AaryanDewan Don't you try my edit answer? Any other problems?

Comment: @danche , Could you please copy my whole code in your answer with the required edits!?As I'm a newbie, it’s really confusing to add what you’ve mentioned at the desired places.

Comment: @AaryanDewan See my edit again. If it works, you can accept it :-P

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to parse the user's input if they don't type the square brackets.

```
evens = []
numbers = input('Please type one or more numbers, separated by commas: ')
for number in numbers.split(','):
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(int(number))
print(evens)
```